# Get Rule List in AppleMail applescript

Tags: string, list, dialog, applescript

Trying to get a dialog to select Mail Rule

```
set ruleList to {}

tell application "Mail" to set end of ruleList to every rule

set theRule to choose from list ruleList
```

Get error

> error "Can’t make {«class rule» "Rule 1" of application "Mail", «class rule» "Rule 2" of application "Mail", «class rule» "Rule 3" of application "Mail"} into type string." number -1700 from {«class rule» "Rule 1", «class rule» "Rule 2", «class rule» "Rule 3"} to string

Tried using

```
set oldDelimits to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "     "
set aRule to (ruleList as string)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimits
```

Still similar error, also tried setting delimiter to "" of application "Mail", rule ""
& its combination( where double quotes were escaped with backslash), nothing worked

any suggestions

Cheers

Comment: Rules are not text, they are **objects**, with various elements and properties - see the scripting dictionary for Mail.app.  Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you could use the rule names in the dialog and match the selection with the rule.

Comment: Thanks for replying  @red_menace, I tried for a generic script to prompt (run from script editor menu), to ask which Rule (have several which wud do different things such as move message to junk/ different mailboxes or forward to various emails), then add the email to the rule. I have a working script for this part. I have made individual script for each Rule, its a pain running them. Idea was to get List of rule, dialog prompt to select Rule, and add the email to the selected rule. I was trying to get the Rule names to the List (ruleList), can u plz advise how do I match with rule. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Mail rule is an object that has various elements and properties (refer to Mail's scripting dictionary for more information), but the items for a `choose from list` dialog need to be **text**.  One of the rule properties is its `name`, which can be used for the dialog.

The following handler gets the rule names for the dialog, and the choice from the dialog is used to return the rule:

```
to getMailRule() -- choose rule by name
    tell application "Mail"
        set choice to (choose from list (get name of every rule))
        if choice is false then -- cancel
            return missing value
        else
            return first item of (get rules whose name is (choice as string))
        end if
    end tell
end getMailRule

return properties of getMailRule() -- do something with a Mail rule
```

Comment: " but the items for a choose from list dialog need to be text", → Got it, Thank u @red_menace